# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 TagBuilder add Newline after tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am building such kind of `ul` using class `TagBuilder`

```
var ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
...
foreach(..items...)
{
  var liTag = new TagBuilder("li");
  ....
  ulTag.InnerHtml += liTag.ToString();
}

return new MvcHtmlString(ulTag.ToString());
```

But the output html getting produced in one line like that

```
<ul id="menu"><li><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="/About">About</a></li>.....</ul>
```

But i want to have it like that:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/About">About</a></li>
    .....
</ul>
```

Is there any way to add `\r\t` or kind of `Environment.NewLine` after each tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really a clean way but it might work:

```
var ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
ulTag.InnerHTML += Environment.NewLine;
foreach(..items...)
{
    var liTag = new TagBuilder("li");
    ulTag.InnerHTML += string.Format("  {0}{1}", liTag.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yep i am figure out this as well, mark your answer as answer in 5 mins. Looks like there is no need to add **\t** ?

Comment: Without adding **\t** output **<ul>** list looks a bit ugly...What do you think?

Comment: @Joper, you may try adding `\t` instead of the whitespaces in the beginning of the line. Personally I don't really care about the formatting of the HTML output as long as it is valid because it is browsers that are reading it, not humans. It also makes the pages smaller if you don't put all those spaces but it's up to you to decide.